# How to parse formData request in laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, form-data

I have fetch api call from Vue js code which sends form-data to laravel backend
I am posting request. Please suggest how to parse this using laravel request?

```html
POST /acapp/public/api/createmember HTTP/1.1
Accept:          */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,mr-IN;q=0.8,mr;q=0.7,ur-PK;q=0.6,ur;q=0.5,hi-IN;q=0.4,hi;q=0.3
Cache-Control:   no-cache
Connection:      keep-alive
Content-Length:  142
Content-Type:    application/json
Host:            localhost
Mimetype:        multipart/form-data
Origin:          chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop
Postman-Token:   cd1ca586-560b-fdf7-3fd6-afe2f457d676
User-Agent:      Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36

------WebKitFormBoundaryoMWbAbNZyySY3vCB
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="dob"

45345345
------WebKitFormBoundaryoMWbAbNZyySY3vCB--
```

Comment: Laravel should be parsing it automatically.

Comment: I tried doing $request->dob; getting no value.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to parse the request. The HTTP-Request Stack of Laravel will do it automatically and call your action you defined for that url.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests

Here is a good example how to get informations from your request. So you don't have to think about that. In the documentation you can find a part how to write VUE components.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/frontend

i think that could help you.

Comment: According to you, $request->dob should give me value for dob in above request. But, I am getting empty response.

Comment: Perhaps the CSRF protection is a problem. When you don't have the security key in your form then it's possible that you don't get a proper form. 

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/csrf

And you should use the form method to validate it. What is with `$field = Input::get('bob');`